# DB Migration Error with Rails App on Heroku (Can't Find User ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

apologies if this has been asked before. With my rails app, everything works fine in development, but when pushing to Heroku, I run into an issue where it is trying to find a User with ID of '1', but the database is empty. I have migrated, reset, and seeded the db but still get the error from Heroku Logs.

It seems like the problem is in my _userportal partial embedded in the articles/index.html.erb file, which calls the current_user and logged_in? methods from ApplicationController.

It seems like the answer should pop out at me, as it must have to do with the finding User.find(session[:user_id]). Or rather, the database has not been properly reset once pushed to heroku. In the heroku rails console, the User.count is 0, but the app is trying to find a User with ID of '1'. I'm not sure why that is.

From the heroku logs:

```
2019-05-23T00:02:43.803680+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe18170f-fab4-4495-8fe2-b2502762afb9]   Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (8.5ms)
2019-05-23T00:02:43.803865+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe18170f-fab4-4495-8fe2-b2502762afb9] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
2019-05-23T00:02:43.805254+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe18170f-fab4-4495-8fe2-b2502762afb9]   
2019-05-23T00:02:43.805305+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe18170f-fab4-4495-8fe2-b2502762afb9] ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=1):
2019-05-23T00:02:43.805348+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe18170f-fab4-4495-8fe2-b2502762afb9]   
2019-05-23T00:02:43.805403+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe18170f-fab4-4495-8fe2-b2502762afb9] app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4:in `current_user'
2019-05-23T00:02:43.805405+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe18170f-fab4-4495-8fe2-b2502762afb9] app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in `logged_in?'
```

ApplicationController.rb:

```
def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
    else
        @current_user = nil
    end
end

def logged_in?
    !!current_user
end
```

_userportal.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="userportal">
        <div class="sessionsection">
            <% if logged_in? %>
                Logged in as <%= current_user.username %>.
                <br>
                <br>
                <%= button_to 'Log Out', logout_path, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to 'Sign Up', signup_path %> or 
                <%= link_to 'Log In', login_path %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="actionsection">
            <%= link_to 'Create a post', current_user ? post_path : signup_path %>
            <hr>
            <%= link_to 'See All Posts', blog_path %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Heroku console:

```
irb(main):005:0> User.count
   (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
=> 0
```

Heroku should render current_user to be nil, and not logged in correct?

Thank you to all that help out! Please advise if I should supply more code/info.

**UPDATE:**

The fix was in the current_user method. Changing:

```
@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
```

to:

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
```

Worked!

Comment: `ActiveRecord#find` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if the record is not found. If you want to silently fail, use `ActiveRecord#find_by`

Comment: Noted. Changing find to find_by was the fix I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `find_by(id: val)` so that it will return `nil` instead of an exception.

```
def current_user
    if session[:user_id]
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    else
        @current_user = nil
    end
end
```

With that `current_user` will be `nil` if user id in session does not exists.

Comment: Amazing, you are my favorite person. That worked. Thank you so much!